# Chat conversation container in a Java form

Tags: java

I have a Java form, and I want to add a chat container featuring all the conversations you had with a contact. So far I want to create a panel, and every time the user gets a message, it gets appended to the panel as a JLabel, it should also have the name of the sender, and it would be another JLabel in bold, bigger font, another color, etc.

Is there a better way of approaching this? Basically I would like to have a container that can append strings in a formatted way dynamically without recurring to JLabels.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on JTextPane.
I think it does what you need.
for example,it can render html formatted strings.
here is a pseudo code

```
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

public class MessagesTextPane extends JTextPane
{

MessagesTextPane()
{
    super();
    //setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED,Font.BOLD,20));
    setContentType("text/html");
    div="<table>"
           +"<tr style=\"color:#"+ clrn +";  font-family:Verdana; font-size:12pt\">"
           +"<td valign=\"top\" ><img  align=\"top\" src=\"" 
           +this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("user.png").toString()
           +"\" /></td>"
           +"<td> <b>"+ msg.senderName + "</b><br/>"
           + msg.msg
           +"</td>"
           +"</tr>"
           +"</table> ";
    setText(div);
    validate();
}
}
```